# Access/Permission denied in JS creating new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to create a new window with HTML returned from a servlet, but I keep getting either

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied

or

> SCRIPT70: Permission is denied

This is code I've used before, not sure why it's not working now.

The javascript function:

```
function getVerification() {
  var userId = jQuery('#userId').val();
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'WorkRequest',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
      formType: 'getVerificationHTML',
      userId: userId
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    async: false,
    success: function (responseText) {
      alert(responseText);
      var newWin = window.open("Verification", '_blank');
      newWin.document.write(responseText);
      newWin.document.close();
    }, 
    error: function (request, status, error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  });
}
```

The error is generated on

`newWin.document.write(responseText);`

The HTML being returned by the servlet is properly formatted.

I'm using a Tomcat server with IE11 (Edge), if that helps.

Comment: This may help you - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/07b6acec-b345-4e43-9f9c-c7319d632ba1/how-to-resolve-quotscript70-permission-deniedquot-on-ie10?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: `asynch: false` is a typo (`aync` without the h), but you don't want to do this anyway...synchronous AJAX is deprecated because it produces a poor user experience. And since you're handling the response correctly via a callback, you don't actually need it either.

Comment: @AlexMulchinock: No, it didn't.  Thanks for the try, tho.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for the info!

Comment: Update: Ran it in Chrome, and it works fine.

Comment: I think it's an IE problem. Your code seems to be correct

Comment: Since you want to display some content from the server, is there any reason you can't just ditch the AJAX request and run `window.open("http://www.example.com/WorkRequest?formType=getVerificationHTML&userId=" + userId, '_blank');` directly?

Comment: @ADyson EXCELLENT workaround.  Still would like to know why the code doesn't work as written on IE11, tho.

Comment: It wouldn't say "workaround" so much as "more direct route to the goal", but thanks :-)

Comment: As for why it does it, I can't be sure but potentially it might be related to the content of the HTML you're trying to inject into the window. Does it, for instance, contain any script tags, or calls out to 3rd-party sites, or anything like that? A very brief bit of googling suggests those could be potential reasons for IE rejecting the content.

Comment: I have tried to create a sample using window.open() method and the document.write() method to write content on the opened page, it seems that everything works well on my side (using local application and IE11/Edge). So, I suggest you try to check the request, whether it is a CROS request and make sure you have permission to access/write the page content.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT:  I've got pretty much the exact same code using the same processes running in 5-6 other projects with no issues.   Why it doesn't work in this one baffles me.